# Function from External file is not defined [JS]

Tags: javascript, function, shopify-app, external-js

Hello I have a problem with JavaScript function.
I have 3 external JS files that are included to my JS file like that:

```
var badgeJs = document.createElement('script');
badgeJs.type = 'text/javascript';
badgeJs.src = 'url'
document.head.appendChild(badgeJs);
```

So here is the problem I need to use 3 functions, but sometimes I received error
`Refference error: functionName is not defined`, after that I refresh the page and first function works but second one no, and every time on refresh some of functions are not defined.
I don't know what is the problem and why this happen? Any advice will be appreciate.
I don't know if this is gonna help but JS code is for a `shopify-app`

How I call functions

```
var content = 'function1(param);function2(param1, param2, param3, [10, 25]);function3(param1, param2);';
(function() { var script = document.createElement('script'); script.text = content; var body = document.querySelector('body'); body.append(script);})();
```

Comment: Please add the piece of code where you are importing and how you are exporting the functions.